# Catch exception thrown in generator caller in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, coroutine

I'm trying to catch an exception thrown in the caller of a generator:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def gen():
    for i in range(3):
        try:
            yield i
        except MyException:
            print 'handled exception'

for i in gen():
    print i
    raise MyException
```

This outputs

```
$ python x.py
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise MyException
__main__.MyException
```

when I was intending for it to output

```
$ python x.py
0
handled exception
1
handled exception
2
handled exception
```

In retrospect, I think this is because the caller has a different stack from the generator, so the exception isn't bubbled up to the generator. ***Is that correct? Is there some other way to catch exceptions raised in the caller?***

*Aside:* I can make it work using [generator.throw()](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.throw), but that requires modifying the caller:

```
def gen():
    for i in range(3):
        try:
            yield i
        except MyException:
            print 'handled exception'
            yield

import sys
g = gen()
for i in g:
    try:
        print i
        raise MyException
    except:
        g.throw(*sys.exc_info())
```

Comment: `yield`ing a value with `yield <variable name>` can never cause an exception. Think of the generator as essentially "paused" between yielding the value. How would exceptions be handled if you did `a = gen(); next(a); raise MyException`?

Comment: That's never going to work. The generator doesn't have any way to get involved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be thinking that when execution hits `yield` in the generator, the generator executes the body of the `for` loop, sort of like a Ruby function with `yield` and a block. That's not how things work in Python.

When execution hits `yield`, the generator's stack frame is suspended and removed from the stack, and control returns to the code that (implicitly) called the generator's `next` method. That code then enters the loop body. At the time the exception is raised, the generator's stack frame is not on the stack, and the exception does not go through the generator as it bubbles up.

The generator has no way to respond to this exception.

Comment: Thanks. Ruby's yield/blocks was indeed the (incorrect) mental model I had when I wrote that.

Answer (score 2):

You might also have gotten confused - as I was just now and arriving here - by the `yield` in the context managers (`contextlib.contextmanager`).
Their usage can be:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def mycontext():
    try:
        yield
    except MyException:
        print 'handled exception'
```

So my solution to a similar case to what you described above is:

```py
def gen():
    for i in range(3):
        yield i


for ii in gen():
    with mycontext():
        print ii
        raise MyException
```

Which gives the *expected* output and uses all of the yields.

A bit late to the party here, but maybe someone with similar knots in their minds will find it helpful.

**Note: putting the context INSIDE the generator will be the same mistake as using `try ... except` there!!**